# POST request in JS not reading JSON string values correctly

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, curl

I am trying to create a registration page using node.js ,html and js. My login command works, but I tried to copy and modify the same code a bit but couldn't get it to register. It shows a Type Error in the browser. The server works fine. I tried to send a command using curl and it works fine too.

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content_Type: application/json' --data '{"username":"rkmenon235","password":"rkm235"}' http://eorlundgraymane.imad.hasura-app.io/create-user
```

The error I get when I use the webpage to post is this

```
TypeError: Not a buffer
   at TypeError (native)
   at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:562:20)
   at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:553:10)
   at hash (/home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/server.js:22:22)
   at /home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/server.js:62:17
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /home/rkm/Desktop/webapp/imad-2016-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
```

This is my Javascript code  (main.js) I used for the registration command.

```
var regy = document.getElementById('signupbutton');
regy.onclick = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(request.status === 200)
                {
                    console.log("user created");
                    alert("Creates Account successfully");      
                }
            else if(request.status === 403){
                alert('Something is 404');
            }
            else if(request.status === 500){
                alert('Something is wrong on the server 500');
            }
        }
    };
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
console.log(username);
console.log(password);
request.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/create-user',true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password}));
};
```

This is my server code (server.js) which responds to the POST request

I have this at the top of my server codes

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var Pool = require('pg').Pool;//Postgres connetion pool
var crypto = require('crypto');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then I have this specific request handlers (also part of server.js)

```
app.post('/create-user',function(req,res){

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex');
    var dbString = hash(password,salt);
    pool.query('INSERT INTO users (username,passwordhash) VALUES ($1,$2)',[username,dbString],function(err,result){
            if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err.toString());
        }
        else
            {
                    res.send('User Successfully created !'+username);
            }
    });
});
```

This is the HTML Code

```
<html>
    <link href = "/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/scripts/coderider"></script>
    <body id = "bodyback">
        <div id = "container">
        <div id = "loginpane">
            <form action = "/create-user" method = "POST">
            <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username" placeholder = "Username"/><br>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "Password"/>
            <br>
            <input type = "submit"  id = "signupbutton" name = "signupbutton" value = "Sign Up"/>
            <br>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/main.js"></script>
```

I repeat the code works fine when using CURL from terminal But I cant register using the POST call from a html page using javascript.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Are your `username` and `password` being passed as `string` values properly?.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the server.js config codes right after the main.js codes

Comment: Does this error occur while registration (or) with your insert statements?

Comment: registration comand

Comment: Can you please try changing your existing `request.send(JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password}));
` to `request.send(new Buffer(JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password})).toString());` and see if it works?

Comment: it didnt work but I found the problem . The problem was that the text fields were not detected by the script because of the delay in loading the elements. I created a separate JS file for the the signup so that it loads the element when the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue with Cross-Domain request.
Try to add header to your Node.js

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that I had given the script link for both the login and submit pages to the same file . The text elements were created in the same script but two different files . This was not a guaranteed task as the elements would not be ready to be called using the document.getElementbyId();

So I created a separate script for each page and called the document element. this time I tested using the console.lo to debug and it worked like a charm